# function returns multiple columns as a single column instead of multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a function in PostgreSQL 9.04 attempting to use a variable which will be used in a select statement then return the results.

The statement I have is simple and works; however, all the columns are outputing to a single column instead of multiple columns.

My function:

```
create or replace function foo(IN pID integer, OUT project_id integer, OUT project_name    text, OUT project_type text, OUT project_description text, OUT project_status text)
returns setof record as

$$
select project_id, project_name, project_type, project_description, project_status from     t_projects
where project_id = $1;
$$

LANGUAGE SQL;

select foo(6) -- runs function
```

The current output looks like this:

```
"(6,"test project","inbound","inbound test","processing")"
```

How can I make it so the results are not concatenated together and return each column item separately?

Comment: Why do you have a return type of `setof record` while also declaring `OUT` columns that match the `SELECT`?  Do you intend to return records, or populate the `OUT` parameters?  You should pick one approach, not both.

Comment: postgresql is still new to me as I am used to working in microsoft sql erver. Ideally, I would like to return the results from the select statement. In my google searches I found that people would create a type with the designated output or would put the outputs in the function. Currently, I am still in the understanding phase of postgresql :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you need to call the function like this:

```
select * from foo(6);
```

which will return something like this:

```
project_id | project_name | project_type | project_description | project_status
-----------|--------------|--------------|---------------------|----------------
         6 | test project |      inbound |        inbound test |     processing
```

it's a quirk of postgres that it can be called both ways and give you a result. you might want to check the docs on set returning functions some more, there are other ways to do this as well. Oh, there is a wiki page on it, written for plpgsql, but most applies to sql functions as well: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions

Comment: Why `select * from foo(6)`  is a error when defining foo() with `create or replace function foo( int) returns setof record as $$ SELECT $1 as a, 'xx' as b; $$ LANGUAGE SQL;` ??

Comment: @Peter-Krauss  

Well, if you call it you get:  
  
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"  
  
Which means that Postgres doesn't understand what the structure of your returned values should be. You need to either add OUT params, like in the original question, or call it with a definition list: 
   
    `pagila=# select * from foo(1) f (a int, b unknown);
    WARNING:  column "b" has type "unknown"
    DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
    a | b
    ---+----
    1 | xx
    (1 row)`