# What is the correct way to define a Postgres SQL-lang function that returns multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have the following function, based on the [SQL Functions Returning Sets](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/xfunc-sql.html) section of the PG docs, which accepts two arrays of equal length, and unpacks them into a set of rows with two columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unpack_test(
    in_int INTEGER[],
    in_double DOUBLE PRECISION[],
    OUT out_int INTEGER,
    OUT out_double DOUBLE PRECISION
) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
    SELECT $1[rowx] AS out_int, $2[rowx] AS out_double
    FROM generate_series(1, array_upper($1, 1)) AS rowx;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

I execute the function in PGAdmin3, like this:

```
SELECT unpack_test(int_col, double_col) FROM test_data
```

It basically works, but the output looks like this:

```
|unpack_test|
|record     |
|-----------|
|(1, 1)     |
|-----------|
|(2, 2)     |
|-----------|
 ...
```

In other words, the result is a single record, as opposed to two columns.  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072021/function-returns-multiple-columns-as-a-single-column-instead-of-multiple-columns) that seems to provide an answer, but it deals with a function that selects from a table directly, whereas mine accepts the columns as arguments, since it needs to generate the series used to iterate over them.  I therefore can't call it using `SELECT * FROM function`, as suggested in that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to [create a type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html) for the return value of your function. Something like this could work:

```
CREATE TYPE unpack_test_type AS (out_int int, out_double double precision);
```

Then change your function to return this type instead of `record`.

Then you can use it like this:

```
SELECT (unpack_test).out_int, (unpack_test).out_double FROM
        (SELECT unpack_test(int_col, double_col) FROM test_data) as test
```

It doesn't seem possible to take a function returning a generic record type and use it in this manner.

Comment: Your SQL actually works on its own; it isn't even necessary to create a new type.  The returned record is already an 'anonymous type'; the trick is in accessing its fields.  I had tried a sub-select like yours, but wrote it as unpack_test.out_int or test.out_int.  The secret is to wrap the name in parentheses, as you did, since Postgres apparently requires that syntax.

Comment: @DNS: On 9.0 here, it gives an error "record type has not been registered" when using it without the specific type.

Comment: Interesting; it works on 8.3, so the behavior must have changed.

Comment: @DNS: They did stricten up a lot of stuff with casting in 9.0, e.g. no more automatic cast from integer to text.