# how to return table from jsonb in postgresql stored function?

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions, set-returning-functions

i create function / stored procedure on POSTGRESQL with jsonb table, the problem is return only one row not all row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."someprocedure"("begindate" date, "endate" date)
RETURNS TABLE("a" text, "b" text) 
AS $BODY$
declare 
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    select data->>'a' as a,
           data->>'b' as b 
    from table 
    where cast(timestamp as date) >= '2019-07-18' 
      and cast(timestamp as date) <> '2019-08-01' ;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

expected:

```
table a | table b
data a  | data b
```

reality:

```
someprocedure
a,b
```

Comment: How exactly are you using that function?

Comment: I guess a duplicate of e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072021